# How to change reported speech referring to the quality of a person to indirect speech

Tags: grammar, reported-speech

> Direct speech - **He said to me, "You are honest."**

I've read from many sources where this narration is written in indirect speech as...

> Indirect speech - **He told me that I was honest.**

So as a learner, my question is simple - since being honest is a quality and not an action or something like it, is my doubt valid that the indirect speech in the above example saying that the first person is not honest now?

Comment: Let's say the direct speech occurred at 4:00P Monday, and the indirect speech (i.e., the report of the direct speech) occurred two hours later at 6:00P. At 4:00P, using the a present-tense verb the speaker comments on the current honesty of somebody. The speaker is not talking about honesty at a later time, say 6:00P. To do that the speaker would have to use a future-tense verb. At 6:00P, when the reporter transposes the verb to the past tense, he is reporting the speaker's belief as of 4:00P, a belief which does not extend to 6:00P.

Comment: @user105719 so it's a assumption and totally depend on context. If I say to you now about your quality, "You are honest". After two hours you can't report it like, he told me that I was honest. If it's about your quality, you would say, He told me that I'm honest. It's not about honesty at a particular instant but a quality. Or is it different thing?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the distinction between honesty and quality. Both can change, no? I can be honest at 4:00P and it might be the case that I'm dishonest two hours later at 6. The indirect report of "You are honest (now)" is "[he said] I was honest (then)"

Comment: @user105719 Let's take another example: If I say "I'm a jolly person", it means that, independently of the context, I tend to be jolly. However, if I say "During the party, I was jolly", it means that in that particular context, I was jolly, but I could be grumpy most of the time.

Comment: @user105719 that's what I'm saying. If the speech is about tendency to be jolly, reported speech would be ' he said that he is jolly' if we write he was jolly, then it contradict the tendency. Same rule is applicable for being honest. If it's characteristic of a person to be honest, then reported speech would be in present tense, not past.

Comment: @WilliamA. Sorry it took me so long. I blame the late hour. And the drugs, of course.  Yes, the present tense can indicate long-standing or on-going action that is expected to continue. It's sometimes called the enduring present tense. My favorite example is "The earth goes around the sun." It has for a long time, it does now, and it will presumably continue to do so. Since the enduring present has past meaning, it won't be backshifted in indirect speech, so: "Galileo said that the earth goes around the sun."

Answer (score 1):

Classically, the past tense has been used for indirect speech (e.g. *He told me that I was honest*), but that is changing. If the condition / quality / etc. expressed is known to be or likely to be still true, the present tense if often used nowadays (e.g. *He told me that I am honest*).

Therefore, depending on the context and on the age of the text, the sentence can mean "I was honest at a particular time" or "I am a honest person".